# How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)

Tags: environment-variables, path

This is irritating me. I seen several suggestions (all using different files and syntax) and none of them worked.

How do I set an environment variable for a specific user? I am on debian squeeze.
What is the exact syntax I should put in the file to make ABC = "123"?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: editing .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile and .ssh/eviroment. Although i dont know if i wrote it in the right location or had the right syntax each time

Comment: `.bashrc` is the main place for that.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: ok but... even after having the solution i tried setting ABC1 and ABC2 at the start and end of that file and it isnt set in my environment.

Comment: Check that `.bash_profile` contains something like `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: what the heck!? i tried ssh-ing in and the variables i set in `.bashrc` show but not the ones in `.bash_profile`! ok, easy fix but... i dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: thanks. Somehow i notice that line adds in bashrc UNLESS i stick a new line (making it 2lines with the second one empty). I'm clueless but it works with one line so i am happy

Comment: This is not a full answer, but if it's shell-specific, I recommend putting it in `.bashrc`; if it's not, put it in `.profile`. I source `.profile` and `.bashrc` (in that order) from `.bash_profile`, and make sure to put `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` on the top of `.bashrc`.

Comment: // , Any way to do this without putting the values in a disk file?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You have to put the declaration in the initialization files of your shell:

- If you are using bash, ash, ksh or some other Bourne-style shell, you can add

  ```
  ABC="123"; export ABC
  ```

  in your `.profile` file (`${HOME}/.profile`). This is the default situation on most Unix installations, and in particular on Debian.

  If your login shell is bash, you can use `.bash_profile` (`${HOME}/.bash_profile`) or `.bash_login` instead.

  **Note:** If either of these files exists and your login shell is bash, `.profile` is not read when you log in over ssh or on a text console, but it might still be read instead of `.bash_profile` if you log in from the GUI. Also, if there is no `.bash_profile`, then use `.bashrc`.
- If you've set zsh as your login shell, use `~/.zprofile` instead of `~/.profile`.
- If you are using tcsh, add

  ```
  setenv ABC "123"
  ```

  in `.login` file (`${HOME}/.login`)
- if you are using another shell look at the shell manual how to define environment variables and which files are executed at the shell startup.

Comment: that was one of the things i tried. i stuck `export ABC="123"` at the end of ~/.profile right now, exit (to root) then su back into that user and it didnt work. I checked by writing env and echo $ABC -edit- i am using bash. But i think the shell is a softlink located at `/bin/sh`

Comment: The default behavior of `su user` is to change ownership of the current shell to the username arg, while keeping the home directory and environment of the calling user.  

To enter a shell in such a way as to become the new user, and gain all of their environmental settings ( $PATH, $HOME, $ABC, etc) you need to pass a - as the first argument to su.

`su - username` will accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: Wait: what do you mean by "exited to root"? In any case making an 'su' does **not** initialize the shell. You need 'su -' (see `man su`)

Comment: oh wow i didnt know that. Thanks @TimKennedy. However i still dont see the variable i set when using `su - theuser` :(

Comment: To check if your .bashrc (or .profile) is correct: `source .bashrc`. Is then the variable set?

Comment: Why did you `su` in the first place? Didn't you just create a root-owned `.profile` that cannot be used by the user?

Comment: @Matteo ?. It returns me nothing. No error, no msg, nothing. Although if i write `export VAR="val"` at the end of `.bash_profile` which i had to create and use su - user i do get results :D

Comment: @acid this is what is *should* have done. The question is, what is sourced when you log in. To check that, log *out* first.

Comment: Because `.profile` is read by all Bourne-compatible shells, you should not write Bash syntax in that file.  In particular, `export VARIABLE=value` needs to be refactored into `VARIABLE=value; export VARIABLE`.

Comment: In Fedora: "/home/joshnoe/.profile: No such file or directory"

Comment: @JoshNoe if it does not exist create it

Comment: I use `zsh`. Will the `.zprofile` as describe above be read before `.zshrc` when `login` or when doing `exec zsh`?

Comment: export VARIABLE=value is perfecly fine in your .profile.  It is recognized by all the Bourne-style shells mentioned by Matteo, as well as dash.  The original Bourne shell itself may not accept this idiom, but why should you be limited in your scripts by the (lack of) features of a 45-year old program that you will not be using?  (Nowadays /bin/sh is usually a symlink to either /bin/bash or /bin/dash, rather than the feature-poor Bourne shell.)

Answer (score 59):

Use `/etc/environment` file for setting the environment variables. Then add the following line inside the `/etc/environment` file.

```
ABC="123"
```

Now the *ABC* variable will be accessible from all the user sessions. To test the variable output first refresh the environment variable using command

```
source /etc/environment
```

and run `echo $ABC`.

Comment: Be careful that `/etc/environment` doesn't support the full bash syntax, something I figured out the hard way. For example, putting `PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"` and then doing `PATH="$PATH:/foo/bar"` on a following line won't work

Comment: Unsure if this is a personal issue or what, but I had to reboot my OS after setting this in `/etc/environment`, even if I restarted the bash terminal or typed `source /etc/environment`. So if you're having issues where the environment variable isn't perpetuating, try rebooting.

Comment: The question is about setting it for a single user. I think `/etc/environment` is for all users on a machine.

Comment: this one is the one that worked for me. many thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is a general procedure you can use for pretty much any shell. In any case, you have to know which shell the user would normally log in with:

```
path="$(grep $USER /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 7)"
shell="$(basename -- "$path")"
```

Then you have to figure out which dot-files this shell would normally read:

```
man $shell
```

A shortcut which might work is to list those dot-files which contain the shell name:

```
ls ~/.*${shell}*
```

If you want to check if one of the files is actually read during login, you can simply print the file name in each of them, for example:

```
echo .bashrc
```

When logging in, you should then see which files are being read, and you can decide which one to modify. Beware that you should not to try to use `echo "$0"` or similar, because the value of `$0` depends on how the shell processes dot-files, and could be misleading.

When it comes to declaring the variable "permanently", note that this only extends to the session. There is no way to access the value of a variable without a session, so it has no meaning outside of one. If you mean "read-only", that is shell dependent, and in **Bash** you can use:

```
declare -r VAR
```

if it already has a value, or

```
declare -r VAR=value
```

to assign it at the same time. Not all shells have this feature.

To declare a variable in most shells, you should use a variable name (`[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*`), followed by an equal sign (and *no spaces* around the equal sign), then a value (preferably quoted unless the value is a simple `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`). For example:

```
name="John Doe"
ip=127.0.0.1
HORRIBLE=1
```

Answer (score 8):

Use export.

```
export ABC="123"
```

To check if it's set, use

```
env
```

and/or

```
env | grep ABC
```

To add it permanently, add this to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export ABC="123"
```

Comment: He wants to know hot to define it _permanently_, i.e., in which file to put the definition.

Comment: Doesnt work. Once i log out the variable is gone. I need it across sessions

Comment: you mean `permenate` and not `permenently` :D

Comment: look at edit for `bashrc`

Comment: I tried .bashrc and .bash_profile with no luck

Comment: whats `permenate`? do you mean `permanent`?

Answer (score 2):

Exact command is:

```
echo 'export ABC = "123"' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Exactly? Seriously? What shell (a) reads `~/.profile` and (b) allows space before and after `=`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way that worked for me is modifying the .bashrc file in the BASH shell.

use this for example:

1. open your .bashrc file
2. add this line:

   ```
   export <VARIABLE> = "<ANY PATH/VALUE you want>"
   ```

   eg : `export HOME = "/home/user/"`

   Remember to use `""` as using `' '` will not work and your bashrc file will report error while sourcing.
3. source it in the current session.

I also tried to modify the /etc/environment file but it didn't allow me to create a new environment variable and when I sourced it, it prompted error that the defined variable is not found.