# Update Linux Path permanently

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

How can I permanently modify the PATH variable in Ubuntu? Is it possible to do it without modifying any files?

I currently use `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/bin` but each time I open a new terminal I have to type it again.

Answer (score 5):

Your `PATH` comes from a text file (usually `~/.bash_profile`).  There really isn't a way to edit it without changing your profile short of doming something like

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually I just throw that exact command you have in my ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

put this line into you .bashrc or .profile file in ~/
Then it is loaded whenever you start your console session

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just a command.

You have to edit the bashrc file for either the system installation or your personal one for permanent changes to take effect.