# How to set environment variable JAVA_HOME that will be saved on exit?

Tags: environment-variables, path, java, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

I use Suse. First I had jdk7 installed, so `JAVA_HOME` was:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/
```

I uninstalled jdk7 and installed jdk6, but I cannot figure out how to change `JAVA_HOME`. `.bashrc` and `.profile` don't contain anything about `JAVA_HOME`.

Is there another file?

Comment: yes, it is, I forgot about profile in my home directory. thanks. Please answer I will close the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set environment variables in `~/.profile`, e.g. by adding this line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05
```

Comment: I don't know Suse, but wouldn't it be better to define this in the system profile?  JAVA_HOME is defined in /etc/profile on my Solaris server (a system with many accounts).

Comment: @BobDuell Yes, you are right.  If the java install was intended for all users system-wide, then `/etc/profile` would be the more appropriate place.

Answer (score 6):

Add to **`/etc/profile.local`**:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

That way it will be set for all users and will be independent of the release or patch-number. `/usr/java/latest` is a link to the latest installed version and exists since JDK/JRE 1.6