# openSuse /etc/profile.local file does not exist

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I am referring to the following URL
[Setting the JAVA_HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42032/how-to-set-environment-variable-java-home-that-will-be-saved-on-exit?newreg=23a2a9ead6a24fd983f30e6981ca7660)

I am interested in the last solution given by Nils, that edit the /etc/profile.local file, this will set it for all the users. The question is that I am using openSUSE 12.3 and it does not have /etc/profile.local.

What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/profile.local` file used to be the location to make system specific changes that would not be overwritten when `/etc/profile` would get an update.

Your system might still source the file if it exists, you could either check `/etc/profile` to see if it does (search for the `profile.local` filename, or just create the file and try out.

However, if you have a directory `/etc/profile.d`, and if your `/etc/profile` has something like (this is from Ubuntu 12.04) the following in it:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

then this mechanism sources (`. $i`) each of the files found in that directory. 
That is a more modern solution to the single `.local` file (with the advantage of different packages being able to drop in their files and remove them as needed without breaking something else). If your OpenSUSE has something like that, you can just create a file `/etc/profile.d/your_name.sh` and put the required code in there.

If you don't have all of that you can add the lines directly to `/etc/profile`, but you do run the risk of loosing your changes on a package upgrade.

Comment: I have tried this, as there is no file profile.local in /etc/ ,I have created a new /etc/profile.local and edited it with JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05
export JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

From the openSUSE first rows of `/etc/profile` :

```
# /etc/profile for SuSE Linux
#
# PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE /etc/profile. There are chances that your changes
# will be lost during system upgrades. Instead use /etc/profile.local for
# your local settings, favourite global aliases, VISUAL and EDITOR
# variables, etc ...
```

This means that you have to create (from root account) the `/etc/profile.local` . Then `/etc/profile` will automatically source even `/etc/profile.local` that will be preserved upon packages updating.

Answer (score 0):

From my openSuSE 15.2 system's /etc/profile:

```
#
# And now let's see if there is a local profile
# (for options defined by your sysadmin, not SUSE Linux)
#
test -s /etc/profile.local && . /etc/profile.local
```

On our production SLES 12.3 server, it has the same thing.