# How to set environment variables permanently for one user

Tags: environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

I have a user XX and I want to set the env variables for it. I looked for .bash_profile in the home dir but there was none. SO, I tried with .bashrc, but when I try to see the env variables (printenv), my variables are not there. This is killing me. I tried for root, and it works. But it does not work for user XX.

Comment: $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.bash_profile should work. check for the file permission and ownership, it should be owned by user. and login and re-login, if your root user use 'su - userid' to swtich to user.

Comment: There is no .bash_profile file. There is .bashrc and .profile

Comment: @cindy `.profile` is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

export MYVARIABLE="variable-value"

This only works if user XX's default shell is bash since you added the variables in .bashrc.

Answer (score -1):

It should work. You may need to have the user log back in or source the .bashrc file to reload it (`. ~/.bashrc`), but you shouldn't set your env. variables in .bashrc.

You can also create a new `.bash_profile` file containing XX's exports and modify his `.bashrc` to make sure it gets loaded with:

`if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then . ~/.bash_profile; fi`

Comment: No, don't set environment variables in `.bashrc`. Set them in `.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/3085#3085)