# Set persistent environment variable for all users

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, python, environment-variables

I am running Ubuntu on a local PC with the following linux distro/kernel:

```
$ lsb_release -a
>> ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

$ uname -r
>> 4.10.0-33-generic
```

I have a python (3.5) script which calls environment variables via the `os` package.

For the sake of simplicity, let's use the following script, test_script.py:

```
import os

MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
print(MY_VAR)
```

When I run this script from terminal:

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

### ATTEMPT 1

Reference: [1][4]

```
$ MY_VAR=123
$ export MY_VAR
$ echo $MY_VAR
>> 123
$ python test_script.py
>> 123
```

**Success!** ... until I close terminal and reopen terminal. When I do that:

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

### ATTEMPT 2

Reference: [2]

To the end of `/home/USER/.profile`, I add the following lines:

```
# my variable
MYVAR=123
```

Save. Confirm saved.

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

### ATTEMPT 3

Reference: [2]

To the end of `/etc/profile`, I add the following lines:

```
# my variable
MYVAR=123
```

Save. Confirm saved.

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

### ATTEMPT 4

Reference: [2]

Create `myvar.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`

Add the following line:

```
MYVAR=123
```

Save. Confirm saved.

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

### ATTEMPT 5

Reference:  [2][3]

To the end of `/etc/environment`, I add the following line:

```
MYVAR=123
```

Save. Confirm saved.

```
$ python test_script.py
>>  File "test-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>>    MY_VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
>>  File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
>>    raise KeyError(key) from None
>> KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

Please help!  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

1. [How to set environment variables permanently for one user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44512/how-to-set-environment-variables-permanently-for-one-user?rq=1)
2. [Permanent Environment Variable for all users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74076/permanent-environment-variable-for-all-users)
3. [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)
4. [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session?rq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the approaches in attempt 3 or 4, but you need to export the variable; change

```
MYVAR=123
```

to

```
export MYVAR=123
```

Comment: Please, write the whole solution, it'll be more useful.

Comment: This solution did NOT work for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I attempted to create MYVAR=123 even with the export keyword before it, both in /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/myvar.sh however when I echo $MYVAR it is empty.

Comment: @ipkpjersi are you using bash? Are you starting it as a login shell?

Comment: I tried with Bash and Zsh. Zsh is my login shell.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what your login shell is; what matters is whether you’re starting the shell as a login shell. That depends on how you’re starting it: are you starting it from a terminal emulator? If so, which one?

Comment: I may have missed something but in 20.04, #4 only seems to work on the user that is used to login to the shell. #5 works in users that are switched to (interactive shell?) and without restart if you `source /etc/environment` Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641505/2110294