# Being not sudo on debian how to make a .sh execute each time I log in?

Tags: debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

So each time I log on I want to execute a command like `export PATH=~/gcc-4.5.0-g/bin:$PATH`. I have no sudo rights. So how to make a .sh execute each time I log in?

Comment: Place it in your `.profile`

Comment: What does it have to do with sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files located in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach is create a `$HOME/bin` directory that contains links to yours executables files:

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
ln -s $HOME/gcc-4.5.0-g/bin/gcc $HOME/bin/gcc
ln -s $HOME/project-Y/bin/py $HOME/bin/py
```

Now you can export only the main bin directory instead of each each small one. Use `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files located in your home to put  `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`.