# Is GNOME Terminal a type of non-login shell?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, login

According to the answer to [What are login and non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells) on Ask Ubuntu, GNOME Terminal is a type of non-login shell.
As pointed out in the excellent book, *A Practical Guide to Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux, 6th Edition*:

> an interactive non-login shell executes commands in the ~/.bashrc file. The default ~/.bashrc file calls /etc/bashrc.

As a result, `/etc/profile` won't be processed in a non-login shell. However, I found that I have appended the java home path to the `PATH`
variable and, when I use GNOME Terminal and issue the command `java`, everything goes fine. Also, the value of the `PATH` variable is the same as the value I defined in `/etc/profile`.

In view of the above-mentioned facts, there is a conflict, what’s wrong with my understanding?

Comment: See also [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) and [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you log in to your x session via a display manager or in a tty, `/etc/profile` is (usually - apparently it is being in your case, though some graphical shells do not read it) sourced by your shell program. After that, a local file (I'm assuming you're using bash here) `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` will be sourced, and any environment variables defined here will override `/etc/profile` for the current user. This environment is *inherited* by any shell you open within the session. This is why we can [define environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session), such as your PATH, in these files.

When you open gnome-terminal, yes by default that starts a non-login shell, but it inherits your user environment already loaded from the login shell or graphical shell. Since `~/.bashrc` is sourced when starting an interactive shell (eg opening gnome-terminal), it may be used to override *some* elements of the environment (such as PS1).

(gnome-terminal itself is an application, not a shell)

Comment: Do you have a  reliable document that contain the detail you mentioned?

Comment: I learned this from [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/). I can find the relevant section in the pdf copy I have, but I don't think it's online... I will look for another source... @BlueSteel

Answer (score 3):

short: no

long: gnome-terminal is a terminal.  You run a shell in a terminal.  You can run either type of shell (login or not) in a terminal (though gnome-terminal makes it harder than other terminals).

Further reading:

- [Bug 71368: gnome-terminal "update utmp/wtmp" option doesn't work when not using gdm](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=71368)
- [Why isn't gnome-terminal a login shell](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1699229)
- [Configure gnome-terminal to start bash as a login shell, doesn't read .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132276/configure-gnome-terminal-to-start-bash-as-a-login-shell-doesnt-read-bashrc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in BASH.

```
shopt -q login_shell && echo " <<< It's a Login Shell >>> " || echo " <<< It's \"NOT\" a Login Shell >>> "
```

By the way, Gnome Terminal is just a terminal emulator(an application program) that uses shell(more specifically BASH).