# Can't change PS1 value in Gnome terminal v3.28.1 (Linux Mint 19.2 with Cinnamon)

Tags: bash, prompt

I can't change de PS1 prompt value of the **terminal emulator** of Linux Mint 19.2 with Cinnamon. It only works for logins made on the console (F1 to F6).

**The last lines of `.profile` file:**

```
export PS1='my-customized-prompt $'
export PSCOPY=$PS1
```

**After restarting Cinnamon (I've tried also restarting the computer):**
It seems something else, after `.profile`, is changing the `PS1` value, like the terminal emulator or any other bash "feature".

```
luc@lucmint:~$ echo $PSCOPY
my-customized-prompt $
luc@lucmint:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
luc@lucmint:~$
```

**However, when I run bash from command line with "-l" argument or change the user with `su`  command, it works**:

```
luc@lucmint:~$ bash -l
my-customized-prompt $logout
luc@lucmint:~$ su - luc
Password: 
my-customized-prompt $
```

What's going on? Who is overriding the PS1 variable when the terminal emulator is open? And how to prevent it?

**EDIT:**

All hidden files in the home directory:

```
$ ls -ld  ~/.*
drwxr-xr-x 30 luc  luc   4096 Aug 27 14:44 /home/luc/.
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 26 14:27 /home/luc/..
-rw-------  1 luc  luc   4706 Aug 27 14:42 /home/luc/.bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc    220 Aug 26 14:27 /home/luc/.bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc   3771 Aug 27 14:00 /home/luc/.bashrc
drwx------ 10 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:36 /home/luc/.cache
drwxrwxr-x  4 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 15:25 /home/luc/.cinnamon
drwxr-xr-x 14 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:36 /home/luc/.config
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc     27 Aug 26 14:36 /home/luc/.dmrc
drwx------  2 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 14:36 /home/luc/.gconf
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc    112 Aug 26 18:06 /home/luc/.gitconfig
drwx------  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:36 /home/luc/.gnome
drwx------  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 14:36 /home/luc/.gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc    245 Aug 26 18:18 /home/luc/.gtkrc-2.0
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc    516 Aug 26 14:27 /home/luc/.gtkrc-xfce
-rw-------  1 luc  luc   5470 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.ICEauthority
drwxrwxr-x  2 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:33 /home/luc/.icons
drwxr-xr-x  4 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 17:53 /home/luc/.java
-rw-------  1 luc  luc     32 Aug 27 14:20 /home/luc/.lesshst
drwx------  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 14:36 /home/luc/.local
drwx------  5 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 15:04 /home/luc/.mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  7 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 15:49 /home/luc/.nbi
drwxr-xr-x  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 15:54 /home/luc/.netbeans
drwx------  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:36 /home/luc/.pki
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc    938 Aug 27 14:44 /home/luc/.profile
drwx------  2 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 16:49 /home/luc/.ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 luc  luc      0 Aug 26 14:40 /home/luc/.sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxrwxr-x  3 luc  luc   4096 Aug 26 18:19 /home/luc/.themes
-rw-r-----  1 luc  luc      5 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.vboxclient-clipboard.pid
-rw-r-----  1 luc  luc      5 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.vboxclient-display.pid
-rw-r-----  1 luc  luc      5 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.vboxclient-draganddrop.pid
-rw-r-----  1 luc  luc      5 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.vboxclient-seamless.pid
-rw-------  1 luc  luc   8268 Aug 27 14:44 /home/luc/.viminfo
-rw-------  1 luc  luc     52 Aug 27 14:43 /home/luc/.Xauthority
-rw-rw-r--  1 luc  luc    131 Aug 26 18:28 /home/luc/.xinputrc
-rw-------  1 luc  luc  19039 Aug 27 14:44 /home/luc/.xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 luc  luc  97892 Aug 27 14:42 /home/luc/.xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: What does `ls -ld ~/.*` show?

Comment: Also, [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard: done. Added info (plus converted screenshots into texts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash reads `.profile` only from login shells, for other interactive shells it reads `.bashrc` instead. (Same for `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`). On many systems, including Debian, the default `/etc/bash.bashrc` sets `PS1`, so for non-login shells that's what gets used.

Your terminal emulator probably runs the shell as a non-login shell, though at least some can be configured to run a login shell instead. E.g. Gnome terminal should have a "run command as a login shell" checkbox, and if the emulator lets you change the command it invokes, you could use `/bin/bash -l` (the `-l` or `--login` marks a login shell).

If you didn't set `PS1` in one of the `bashrc` files, a shell that was started without `PS1` in the environment would end up with the default `PS1`, giving something like `bash-4.4$`, so it's probably safest to set `PS1` in `bashrc`.

Also note that if the shell is started as a login shell, it will not read `bashrc` by itself. That's why the `profile` files on e.g. Debian do that explicitly.

Related:

- [Configure gnome-terminal to start bash as a login shell, doesn't read .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/q/132276/551198) (AU)
- [/etc/profile not being sourced](https://askubuntu.com/q/40287/551198) (AU)

Comment: How can it set the variable PSCOPY at the end of .profile with the value of PS1 also set in .profile (see my test), but later get the value set in .bashrc if bashrc is being sourced at the beginning of .profile?

Comment: @Luciano, right, if a login shell runs first, it reads `.profile`, where you `export` some variables. Those would then be seen by any child processes, including interactive non-login shells. But they, in turn, would run `.bashrc` (and friends), possibly overriding some of those variables. So `PSCOPY` may just be inherited from when `.profile` originally is processed. In any case, that `PS1` with the `debian_chroot` parts looks a lot like what `bashrc` in Debian sets, so I'd suggest looking through `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I've just found why it happens and how to fix it, it's the `gnome-terminal` behavior, it inherits `.profile` settings loaded once in the current session, as you said. But it can be changed checking the option "run command as a login shell". What about improving your answer adding it? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307999/114939

Comment: @Luciano, yep, added