# PATH variable getting reset after closing and reopening SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, path

I have used SSH (via putty) to connect to a VPC and then added a folder to my path using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my/directory
```

This works whilst the session is open, however when I close putty then reestablish the SSH connection the changes to PATH are no longer there.

Any help understanding why this happens would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PATH variable that you set did not persist because, well, setting
an environment variable is not a persistent operation; it only applies
to the shell you made it in (and possibly its descendant processes).
The shell you get after reconnecting is not the same one you had
before, it's a brand-new one.

To keep a value of PATH that will be set in each new shell you start,
you could add the `export PATH=...` line to one of your shell's init
files; for example `~/.bash_profile` if using bash.

The following question has more detailed answers:
[How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21598/88983)

Comment: That worked, do you want me to delete this question?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I would call your question a complete duplicate (you were asking _why_ the setting was not persistent, not how to make it persistent, although it seems natural that you wanted the second). Do as you see fit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in PATH variable in your .bash_profile file (hidden) which can be found in your home folder.

```
[username@hostname ~]# vi .bash_profile
```