# bash: shutdown: command not found

Tags: debian, environment-variables, path

I installed the latest version of Debian (netinstall). 
I have the problem, that the terminal does not know commands like `shutdown`, `reboot`, and so on. 
When I do `whereis shutdown` it tells me it is in `/usr/sbin`.

I fixed this on a different installation try by writing `/usr/sbin` into `/etc/profile` where the `$PATH` is written. 
But this time it did not work.

I looked at this: https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables, but either those files did not exist or I did not know where to put the path. 
And doing `export PATH=$PATH:usr/sbin` is not permanent, it's gone after reboot, so that is garbage as well.

Edit: Wait, maybe I have to change the PATH in `/etc/environment`?! 
I have to test this once I give Debian another try.

Comment: You usually don't have the `sbin` directories in the `PATH` for a regular user, since the stuff isn't that usable for a regular user. Though with Policykit or such, `shutdown` could be. So I guess an important part here is if it's just the search path or not -- does `shutdown` work for you if you run it as `/usr/bin/shutdown`? For the path, see e.g. [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21598/170373)

Comment: I can do `/usr/sbin/shutdown now` as root, but I want to use the commands without the whole path like in Ubuntu of course...

Comment: I notice that you use `usr/sbin` as the path, without the initial `/`. You may want to make sure that your path contains `/usr/sbin` rather than `usr/sbin`, and that `/etc/profile` is correct too. Note also that you probably want to mention what shell you're using too, as some shells don't care about `/etc/profile` (e.g. `zsh`).

Comment: Note that with the latest debian you might prefer the systemd-way in the first place: `systemctl poweroff` -  you could alias this.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you did to /etc/profile to diagnose what you did wrong.  Debian annoyingly defaults to only giving root sbin on the path, so I always remove the test for root from /etc/profile.

Comment: I did use the initial `/`before `usr/sbin`. I have now switched back to Ubuntu, it has `/usr/sbin` in its path by default. But I'm still clueless why it doesn't work in Debian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Binaries in the `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` directories are intended to be run only be superusers/sudoers. If you want to run anything in there, prefix your command with `sudo`. Your user will need to be a member of the `sudoers` group though.

`$ sudo shutdown -P +0`

For proof of concept, try `which shutdown` vs `sudo which shutdown`.

Comment: `which shutdown` outputs nothing. `sudo which shutdown` outputs: `testuser is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Comment: That means your account isn't allowed to use `sudo`. If you're sure you want to, you can add the user to the `sudo` group with `usermod -aG sudo <username>`, but you'll have to do this on the root account (enter `su` to switch to the root account), or at least another account that can run `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, you were on the right path with `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"`.  What you have to do is edit your `.bashrc` file, and put `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"` at the bottom, save, close.  Then it'll work permanently.

Answer (score 2):

SystemD, through the `polkit` auth agent, allows you to execute those commands (`shutdown`/`reboot`...) transparently:

```bash
systemctl poweroff
```

shuts down the system.

You can even make a Bash alias:

```bash
alias shutdown="systemctl poweroff"
```

And then use `shutdown` transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed "sudo" in debian 11. Then I tried again "shutdown -r now" and the problem has solved.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the accepted answer, except for noting that you needed to install an additional package to implement it. As such, you should consider posting it as a comment below that answer (once you have sufficient reputation) or submit an edit suggestion.

Comment: I upvoted by accident. This is not the correct answer. Correct answer is updating the PATH to include /usr/sbin

Answer (score 0):

## Debian - Unable to shutdown/reboot my Debian ("bash: shutdown: command not found")

Log as root and perform...

```
echo '
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
' | tee -a /root/.bashrc
```

... or explicitly tell the `su` to set environment variable as if the user logs in directly...

```
su -
```

**EXTRA:**

Add an user to the sudo group with

```
usermod -aG sudo <USERNAME>
```

Do this as root (or root capable) account.

[Ref(s).: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664942/61742 ,
https://superuser.com/a/1539749/195840 ]