# Why my Xbox360 wired controller disconnects on rumble?

Tags: arch-linux, steam, games

While playing Dead Cells from Steam, I noticed than when I was hurt, my controlled was somehow disconnected for a few seconds (with an alert message saying so). In this case, the game run a bunch of vibration. If I disable them, it works without trouble. To confirm this, I ran `evtest` and `fftest` as said in the post: [How to enable a vibration in a PC gamepad in Xubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139960/how-to-enable-a-vibration-in-a-pc-gamepad-in-xubuntu-18-10). Here is my output:

```
$ evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event25:     Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
Select the device event number [0-25]: 25
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x45e product 0x28e version 0x114
Input device name: "Microsoft X-Box 360 pad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 314 (BTN_SELECT)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
    Event code 316 (BTN_MODE)
    Event code 317 (BTN_THUMBL)
    Event code 318 (BTN_THUMBR)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value  -1637
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   -377
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 3 (ABS_RX)
      Value   -671
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 4 (ABS_RY)
      Value    161
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 21 (EV_FF)
    Event code 80 (FF_RUMBLE)
    Event code 81 (FF_PERIODIC)
    Event code 88 (FF_SQUARE)
    Event code 89 (FF_TRIANGLE)
    Event code 90 (FF_SINE)
    Event code 96 (FF_GAIN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
^C
```

So my controller is at `/dev/input/event25` and supports rumble.

```
$ fftest /dev/input/event25
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event25 opened
Features:
  * Absolute axes: X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ, Hat 0 X, Hat 0 Y, 
    [3F 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Relative axes: 
    [00 00 ]
  * Force feedback effects types: Periodic, Rumble, Gain, 
    Force feedback periodic effects: Square, Triangle, Sine, 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 07 01 00 00 00 ]
  * Number of simultaneous effects: 16

Setting master gain to 75% ... OK
Uploading effect #0 (Periodic sinusoidal) ... OK (id 0)
Uploading effect #1 (Constant) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #2 (Spring) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #3 (Damper) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... OK (id 1)
Uploading effect #5 (Weak rumble, with light motor) ... OK (id 2)
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
0
Now Playing: Sine vibration
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
4
Play effect: No such device
```

Here `No such device` speaks wonder. My controller was indeed disconnected somehow.

I read [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Gamepad#Xbox_360_controller) and found this:

> If you experience problems with the rumble feature not working in games, it may be necessary to set the environment variable SDL_JOYSTICK_HIDAPI=0

So following [How do I set a user environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67733/150597) , I edited `/etc/environment` with `SDL_JOYSTICK_HIDAPI=0`. Then, I rebooted. No success here.

I also try with the `xboxdrv` as propose in the wiki without success either.

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue with power. I have run into similar issue with one or multiple 360 controllers plugged into an un-powered USB hub.

This was because on an un-powered hub the devices all have to split the current from the upstream port. On a powered hub, every port has its own current limit.

A solution would be to switch to a powered hub or try connecting the controller directly to the computer.

[source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/152392786901386522/)